# Unnecessary asterisk in regex that finds CSS comment

Tags: css, regex, comments, regex-negation

I thought to ask this as an update to my [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329552/883832) but it became too long.

I was trying to understand a regex given in [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) that matches css comments and got this doubt

Why do they use

```
\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*\/
----------------^
```

instead of just

```
\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*\/
```

?

Both are working similarly. Why do they have an extra star there?

1. Let's look at this part:

   ```
   \*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*
   -A- --B--     -C-
   ```

   Regex engine will parse the A part and match all the stars until there is NO MORE stars or there is a line break. So once A is done, the next character must be a line break or anything else that's not a star. Then why instead of using `[^/]` they used `[^/*]`?
2. Also look at the repeating capturing group.

   ([any **one** char that's not / or *][zero or more chars that's not *][one or more stars])

   It captures groups of characters ending with atleast one or more stars. So C will take all the stars leaving B with no stars to match in the next round.

   So the B part won't get a chance to meet any stars at all. That is why I think there's no need to put a star there.

But that regex is in w3.org so I guess my understanding may be wrong. Please explain what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been corrected in the [CSS3 Syntax module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#lexical):

```
\/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*\/   /* ignore comments */
```

Notice that the extraneous asterisk is gone, making this expression identical to what you have.

So it would seem that it was simply a mistake on their part while writing the grammar for CSS2. I'm digging the mailing list archives to see if there's any discussion there that could be relevant.

Comment: OMG! So I was right (and late to find out.) I only thought that they must be right and exhausted my mind trying to find what I'm missing. I didn't think it would have been changed in CSS3. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I am waiting for your link to any relevant discussion.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything :/

Comment: I just pasted the regex in their advanced search and found this only result: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-mobileok-checker/2007Sep/0000.html But I don't understand what they are talking. Okay thanks anyways.

Comment: @Vigneshwaran: That discussion is not related to the grammar itself, so you can ignore it.